# MySQL/PHP <select> not displaying submitted value

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a school assignment and I have run into some issues. I have PHP code for a form that, when selected, sends the selected result to a MySQL database and then loops through and displays the results. The only problem is that, instead of showing the selected `<option>`, it shows all four of the options.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include_once (connection.php);

if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") && (isset($_POST['card_catalog_form']))) {

    $card_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['card_name']);
    $card_label = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['card_label']);

    $insert_card_genre_query = sprintf("INSERT into card_catalog (card_name, card_label) VALUES ('%s', '%s')",
        $card_name,
        $card_label);
    $insert_card_genre = mysqli_query($conn, $insert_card_genre_query) or die (mysqli_error($conn));

    $last_record = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
}

$card_genre_query = "SELECT card_genre.genre_id, card_label from `card_genre` order by card_label asc";
$card_genre = mysqli_query($conn, $card_genre_query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$get_card_genre_query = "SELECT card_catalog.id, card_catalog.card_name, card_catalog.card_label, card_genre.genre_id from card_catalog right join card_genre on card_catalog.card_label = card_genre.card_label";
$get_card_genre = mysqli_query($conn, $get_card_genre_query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>The Marketplace By The Mana Club</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/tmp.css">
</head>
<body>

    <?php include(templatestuff/top_of_tmp.php); ?>

    <main>
        <h1>Products:</h1>
        <section>
            <ul id="products_list">
                <li><b>Product 1: "Jack-In-The-Mox"</b></li>
                <li><b>Product Description: "Roll a six-sided die for Jack-in-the-Mox. On a 1, sacrifice Jack-in-the-Mox and lose 5 life. Otherwise, Jack-in-the-Mox has one of the following effects. Treat this ability as a mana source..."</b></li>
                <img src="productimages/jackinthemox.jpeg" alt="Jack In The Mox"/>
            </ul>
        </section>

        <div>

            <h2>What Card Are You Looking For?</h2>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <fieldset>
                <p><b>What's The Card Name? <input type="text" name="card_name"></b></p>
                <p>
                  <p><b>Card Type:</b></p>
                  <select name="card_genre">
                      <?php while ($row_card_genre = mysqli_fetch_assoc($card_genre)) { ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $row_card_genre['genre_id'];?>"><?php echo $row_card_genre['card_label'];?></option>
                      <?php } ?>
                  </select>
                </p>

                <p><input type="submit"></p>
                <input type="hidden" name="card_catalog_form">
              </fieldset>
            </form>

            <?php
                if ($last_record) {
                    echo "<p><b>You just created form query #" . $last_record ."</b><p>";
                }
            ?>

            <p>You are submitting your form at
                <?php
                    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
                    echo date('g:i a \o\n l, F j, Y');

                ?>
            </p>

        </div>

        <?php
        $query = "SELECT card_catalog.card_name, card_catalog.card_label, card_genre.genre_id FROM card_catalog, card_genre";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo $row['card_name']. " - ". $row['genre_id'];
            echo "<br />";
        }
        ?>

    </main>

    <?php include('templatestuff/bottom_of_tmp.php'); ?>

</body>
</html>`
```

(If you want to see the website that contains the problem, you can go [here](http://themanaclub.com/themarketplace/themarketplace.php))

Any help, or constructive criticism, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What I gathered so far: I choose something in the select, and then below that I should see only things matching my selection. But you are not using a WHERE in your SQL statement. So you are always fetching everything, and not using the value I selected anywhere.

Comment: @colburton Are you talking about this SQL statement: <?php
            $query = "SELECT card_catalog.card_name, card_catalog.card_label, card_genre.genre_id FROM card_catalog, card_genre";?

Comment: Yes. You should look up http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php and get the value for card_genre from $_POST['card_genre']. Do not use it in mysqli_query(). This would lead to a SQL injection!

Comment: So what you're saying is that I shouldn't use the $result and the mysqli_query? Also sorry if I don't understand everything (not _super_ advanced at PHP and MySQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might point you in the right direction:

```
if (isset($_POST['card_genre'])) {
    $query = "SELECT card_catalog.card_name, card_catalog.card_label, card_genre.genre_id FROM card_catalog, card_genre WHERE card_genre.genre_id = ?";
    $stmt   = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['card_genre']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['card_name']." - ".$row['genre_id'];
        echo "<br />";
    }
} else {
    $query = "SELECT card_catalog.card_name, card_catalog.card_label, card_genre.genre_id FROM card_catalog, card_genre";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['card_name']." - ".$row['genre_id'];
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting closer. Now whenever you type in the card_name and select a card_type, it inputs it into the database, but then it also changes every other id to the one that was just submitted. (To see what I meant: http://themanaclub.com/themarketplace/themarketplace.php). Thank you for your help so far

Comment: How do I edit the code so that it doesn't update the entire database and change the values for "genre_id" for everyone. Also I need the "card_label" text to be displayed, not the "genre_id." (_php/sql newbie here_)

Comment: The code that you gave me, although a big step in the right direction, displays a genre_id number, but then, for subsequent entries, resets all former ids to the one just entered. How do I fix this? (anybody else feel free to chime in) @colburton

Comment: This line does the output: echo $row['card_name']." - ".$row['genre_id']; You can use whatever fields you like there. Just replace genre_id with card_label, or any other field from the selected tables.

Comment: Thank you so much @colburton! I changed some things around and now the form is looping through and displaying the value that the user selected. Thankful that this is fixed